# How to use multiple JPA implementations in a Spring Boot project?

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, eclipselink

Is it possible to use multiple JPA implementations in a Spring Boot project ? For example Hibernate for one data source/database and Eclipse Link for another data source/database. If it is possible then how can we use it.

Using Hibernate I successfully handle multiple data source in a single spring boot project. But I don't know how to use multiple JPA in a project .

Comment: there are a number of ways, depending on how you define your persistence unit. You have to define and redefine multiple persistence units for the same set of entities, and have each use a different provider. This is normally done within a persistence.xml file that containers then just use the appropriate context based on the context name, but Spring by default ignores persistence.xml ( https://nieldw.medium.com/jpa-spring-boot-will-not-search-for-meta-inf-persistence-xml-f28f14444d6d ). If using dynamic persistence units in Spring, you'll still need to define LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean

Comment: Note that with byte code enchancement (weaving), it might be better to keep such persistence units, if they are using the same entity classes, in different applications so they are in completely different class loaders. The same entity instance passed to multiple providers may not play nice if they've all put their hooks into the class definition (ie how they support lazy fetching, entity graphs and change tracking and will be very different)

Answer (score -1):

Yes It is possible you can implements as many times you want jpa interface
You need to create different repository for each entity and implements the JpaInterface in each repository
for example-:

```
  @Repository
 public interface CommentRepository extends JpaRepository<Comment,Long> {
  }
```

NOw to use with different class just replace

1- Comment as that class Name
2- and Long as that class id datatype

Comment: How can we specify particular JPA implementation (e.g. Hibernate, EclipseLink) to use in repository ?

Comment: 1:- For HIbernate put this dependency                                                                                                          
                                                                                                                
          <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.11</version>
     </dependency>

Comment: 2- For EclipseLink add this dependency                                                                             <dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.1</version>
</dependency>